# Como criar essa regra no mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho um campo na minha tabela:

```
tipoEndereco char(1);
```

Porém esse campo só recebe dois valores possíveis, que são:

```
  1-> i (Instalação) 
  2-> c (Cobrança)
```

Por causa disso, estou pensando, e gostaria da opinião de vocês, em trocar ele para:

```
tipo enum("i", "c");
```

A mudança é para efeito de performance. O que acham?

A outra orientação, e a mais importante, é que gostaria de criar uma regra no MySQL que permita a inserção de valores vazios nos campos, caso o valor que chegar via query seja "c" (de Cobrança).

Isso é possível?

Eis a tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE enderecos (
  idEnderecos int(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  idClientes int(10) NOT NULL,
  tipoEndereco char(1) NOT NULL,
  endereco varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  numero varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  complemento varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  bairro varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  cidade varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  estado char(2) NOT NULL,
  cep char(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idEnderecos)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

A ideia aqui é que assim que for gravado o cliente na tabela `Clientes`, pegar o seu `idClientes` gerado (`insert_id`) e gravar os dados do endereço na tabela `endereços`.

O formulário tem dois endereços, um de instalação e outro de cobrança. No banco, a tabela endereços esta toda `NOT NULL`. Mas se o endereço for do tipo "c" (cobrança), preciso que a tabela aceite valores nulos.

Como?

Comment: Há conflitos de lógica na sua descrição, melhor revisar o que escreveu. Se nenhum valor for fornecido para o campo (input HTML) for vazio, você quer automaticamente que "c" seja o valor padrão para coluna "tipo", da tabela?

Comment: Valor padrão é i de Instalação

Comment: O campo sendo char(1) e recebendo 1, 2, i, ou c não faz diferença nenhuma pra performance.

Answer (score 1):

1ª Pergunta. Sim, pode haver uma mera melhora de performance, mas se a quantidade de transações simultâneas for pequena, não fará tanta diferença assim. A principal vantagem de utilizar um enum é que vc restringe a quantidade de entradas de um usuário, se bem que via código também pode-se fazer isso. Mas caso seja necessário alterar ou adicionar qualquer tipo ou reutilizar o código, como em subselects, por exemplo, vc terá mais problemas que vantagens, assim como descrito em http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

2ª Sim, é possível. Se vc utilizar tanto procedures como scripts pode ser utilizada uma cláusula CASE para esta inserção.

```
insert into tabela2(end_inst,end_cobr) values(select case when tipo_endereco = 'i' then Endereco else null end, case when tipo_endereco = 'c' then Endereco else null end from tabela1)
```

Mas recomendo que talvez vc reveja o processo de normalização deste banco de dados, pois pelo pouco que percebi podem haver dados redundantes, causando desperdício e perda de confiabilidade no banco

Comment: Neste caso precisarei deixar todos os campos como NULL permitido na hora de criação da tabela? Porque todos estão como NOT NULL. Por isso gostaria de saber se existe jeito de criar a regra, desculpa, não na query (php) mas na própria tabela no banco!

Comment: Adicionei a tabela na pergunta

Comment: Não é possível inserir nulo em campos não nulos, pois a própria regra da tabela exige que vc especifique-os, mesmo os omitindo da instrução insert. Se é mesmo necessário inserir nulo, vc precisará usar um comando de alteração de tabela para remover esta restrição not null. Caso não consiga fazer com sql puro, pode utilizar o mysql Workbench para ajudá-lo

Comment: O que usei acima foi só um exemplo. Cada bloco CASE...end no caso funciona como um campo da tabela, os outros vc pode adicionando normal

Answer (score 0):

Acho uma boa ideia usar ENUM aqui, mas teria sido uma boa ideia também se você TINYINT simulando um **BOOLEAN**.

Mas vamos supor que escolha **ENUM**. Então você precisa entender um pouco os detalhes.
Tipos ENUM são numericamente indexados, o que siginifica que se você tiver isso:
tipo ENUM ('c', 'i');
Então internamente c = 0 e i = 1.
Também, se você quer algo como um campo com valor padrão e diferente de **NULL**, você pode criar um campo ENUM e colocar o valor que você quer que seja sempre padrão (caso não forneçam um) no índice 0, ou seja, o primeiro valor do **ENUM**.
Desse forma, qualquer entrada diferente de **NULL** que não seja um valor válido será automaticamente o valor da indexado na primeira posição do campo **ENUM**.
Veja o que a documentação do [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) diz:

> The value may also be the empty string ('') or NULL under certain
>   circumstances:
>
> 1. If you insert an invalid value into an ENUM (that is, a string not
>      present in the list of permitted values), the empty string is
>      inserted instead as a special error value. This string can be
>      distinguished from a “normal” empty string by the fact that this
>      string has the numeric value 0. More about this later.
>
>    If strict SQL mode is enabled, attempts to insert invalid ENUM
>      values result in an error.
> 2. If an ENUM column is declared to permit NULL, the NULL value is a
>      legal value for the column, and the default value is NULL. If an
>      ENUM column is declared NOT NULL, its default value is the first
>      element of the list of permitted values.

Então:

```
mysql> 
mysql> create table x (
    id int primary key auto_increment, 
    tipo enum('c', 'i') not null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into x(tipo) values ('i');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into x(tipo) values (null);
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'tipo' cannot be null
mysql> insert into x(tipo) values ('');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into x(tipo) values ('nao existe');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.09 sec)

mysql> insert into x(tipo) values ('i');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from x;
+----+------+
| id | tipo |
+----+------+
|  1 | i    |
|  2 |      |
|  3 |      |
|  4 | i    |
+----+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from x where tipo = 0;
+----+------+
| id | tipo |
+----+------+
|  2 |      |
|  3 |      |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Adicionei a tabela na pergunta!

Comment: @CarlosRocha A lógica é a mesma. É esperado de você ao menos algum esforço.

Comment: Esqueci de comentar, desculpe por isso, é que os campos que deverão receber valor nulo embora na criação da tabela esses fields estão NOT NULL, são os campos do endereço propriamente diro. Ou seja: endereco, numero, complemento, bairro, cidade, estado, cep. Esses só deverão PERMITIR valor nulo, caso o valor a ser inserido no field tipo, que chegar por query do php trazer valor "c".

Comment: Mas NOT NULL aceita valor vazio? Ou só não aceita valores "NULL"?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Eu suspeito que você não leu minha resposta. Mas prossigamos... Sim, campos NOT NULL aceitam string vazia, afinal (char/string != NULL).

Comment: INSERT ........... VALUES ("", "", ""). Então passa.
Era isso que eu queria.
Então o que seria um campo Nulo (NULL)?

Comment: @CarlosRocha O que é NULO?

Comment: Obrigado a todos!